# How to use embedded MongoDB with SpringBoot v3.0.0?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, embedded-mongodb

I'm trying to connect embedded mongodb and test it with MongoDbSpringIntegrationTest. The problem is that the identical code works with spring boot in 2.7.7 but doesn't work with spring boot in 3.0.0. The question is how can I enable embedded mongodb for spring boot tests in 3.0.0?

dependencies in pom.xml:
`

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.flapdoodle.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

`

application.properties:
`

```
spring.data.mongodb.database=test
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.mongodb.embedded.version=4.0.2
```

`MongoDbSpringIntegrationTest:`

```
@DataMongoTest
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
public class MongoDbSpringIntegrationTest {
  @DisplayName("given object to save"
      + " when save object using MongoDB template"
      + " then object is saved")
  @Test
  public void test(@Autowired MongoTemplate mongoTemplate) {
    // given
    DBObject objectToSave = BasicDBObjectBuilder.start()
        .add("key", "value")
        .get();

    // when
    mongoTemplate.save(objectToSave, "collection");

    // then
    assertThat(mongoTemplate.findAll(DBObject.class, "collection")).extracting("key")
        .containsOnly("value");
  }
}
```

`

When I run this I get this error:
`org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=localhost:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information}}]`

Comment: Embedded mongo support was dropped in spring 2.7
Check this out: https://github.com/flapdoodle-oss/de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.spring/tree/spring-3.0.x

Answer (score 17):

The embedded mongo dependency you are using has support for `Spring boot 2.7.x` integration. There's a [new version](https://github.com/flapdoodle-oss/de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.spring) for `Spring boot 3.x`. You should only need to make 2 changes to your project:

**Embedded Mongo dependency**

Your `pom.xml` currently has:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>de.flapdoodle.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Change that to:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>de.flapdoodle.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.spring30x</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Notice the `artifactId` is different. Also `4.5.2` is the latest version at the time of this answer, find the latest anytime on [maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/de.flapdoodle.embed/de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.spring30x).

**Mongo version configuration**

Your `application.properties` currently has:

```
spring.mongodb.embedded.version=4.0.2
```

Change that to:

```
de.flapdoodle.mongodb.embedded.version=4.0.2
```

The mongo version config is now resolved from flapdoodle's namespace, not Spring's.

Comment: That works for me. You can also remove `<scope>test</scope>`, disable autoconfiguration, and only turn on embedded MongoDB with certain Spring Boot profiles. There are gotchas here and there. I document the process at [Embedded MongoDB Only in IDE using Spring Boot 3.x](https://www.garretwilson.com/blog/2023/04/02/embedded-mongodb-ide-spring-boot-3).

Comment: import de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.MongodExecutable -> cannot be resolved

Answer (score 3):

Add to build.gradle:

```
// Embedded Mongo
implementation 'de.flapdoodle.embed:de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.spring30x:4.6.2'
```

Add to the test properties next:

```
# Tests
de.flapdoodle.mongodb.embedded.version=5.0.5
```

[image]

And example of test:

```
@SpringBootTest
public class ExampleTest {
    @Autowired
    private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        mongoTemplate.save(MyEntity.builder()
                .name("test")
                .email("test@mail.com")
                .build());
    }
}
```

Comment: this question was using maven

Answer (score 2):

egimaben's answer helped me a lot. Although there need to be some other changes, I will share them within here just in case somebody needs.

I'm using an macbook pro m2 and our project is still using springboot `2.6.x`, with `spring.mongodb.embedded.version: 4.0.2` set in the test application's `application.yaml` file. And it's having issues as I started to use m2 to run the tests.

What I changed in `build.gradle` (like the egimaben's answer for maven):

from

```
testImplementation 'de.flapdoodle.embed:de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo'
```

to

```
testImplementation "de.flapdoodle.embed:de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.spring27x:4.6.0"
```

also need to add:

```
dependencyManagement {
  dependencies {
    dependency group:'de.flapdoodle.embed', name:'de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo', version:"4.6.1"
  }
}
```

the `de.flapdoodle.embed:de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.spring27x:4.6.0` is needed and cannot change to `...spring26x:xxx`, also the version `4.6.0` is important here.

The `dependencyManagement` section is meant to tell spring not use their own embedded mongodb as we are still using `2.6.x`. The `4.6.1` in `dependencyManagement` section looks like the version `4.6.0` for the `...spring27x`, but it's not the same. They are from two different repos:

1. https://github.com/flapdoodle-oss/de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.spring/tree/spring-3.0.x
2. https://github.com/flapdoodle-oss/de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo

And last thing, about the test application's `application.yaml` file, you can now define the newest mongodb version as it is in the official website: https://www.mongodb.com/download-center/community/releases/archive.

I chose `6.0.2` which already supports the m2 with the version `macOS ARM 64: Archive: mongodb-macos-arm64-6.0.2.tgz`. So I changed the version inside the `application.yaml` file:

from

```
spring.mongodb.embedded.version: 4.0.2
```

to

```
de.flapdoodle.mongodb.embedded.version: 6.0.2
```

hope it helps the people with new macbook pro m2

Comment: This should be an edit to egimaben's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot 3 support has been added to flapdoodle as described in [this issue](https://github.com/flapdoodle-oss/de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.spring/issues/2) and i found answer on my question in issues.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could also include the answer to your original problem in this answer.