# Embedded MongoDB with SpringBoot v3.0.0?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, flapdoodle-embed-mongo

I am using emdedded mongodb (flapdoodle) in my tests.
I am moving to Spring Boot 3. I got help from this link:
[How to use embedded MongoDB with SpringBoot v3.0.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74734106/how-to-use-embedded-mongodb-with-springboot-v3-0-0)
(@egimaben answer).

Now if I want to be able to create the mongo client (mongotemplate), I need to know in advance the port.
So I am using a fixed port to start MongoDB server:

spring.data.mongodb.port=27777

Then I create the client (Mongotemplate) to connect to this port.
Everything works fine.

But if I have multiple tests, each test is trying to start MongoDB server and fails since the port is busy.
How can I start/stop embedded MongoDB for each test?
or
If I use random port instead of fixed port, how can I know in advance the random port in order to create the Mongo client (mongoTemplate)?

Thank you for your help.