# Testing MongoRepository with @DataMongoTest end up in TimeOut

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb, flapdoodle-embed-mongo

I have a simple MongoRepository :

```
@Repository
public interface HistoryRepository extends MongoRepository<HistoryWrapper, String>
```

with two method that I want to test, using @DataMongoTest. I don't want to load the full Spring context using @SpringBootTest.

My test configuration looks like this :

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@DataMongoTest
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackageClasses = HistoryRepository.class)
class RatingHistoryRepositoryTest {

@Autowired
private HistoryRepository historyRepository;

@BeforeAll
public void setUp() {
    HistoryWrapper wrapper1 = generateHistoryWrapper(SIREN_1);

    historyRepository.save(wrapper1);
}
```

and in my application.yaml from the test repository :

```
de:
    flapdoodle:
        mongodb:
            embedded:
                version: 4.6.1

spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
    username: sa
    password: sa
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create-drop
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
    properties:
      hibernate:
        default_schema: public
  data:
      mongodb:
          database: database
          port: 27017
```

I always get the following error :

```
Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=localhost:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect}}]; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=localhost:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect}}]
```

And I don't understand why. Anyone has an idea ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74734106/how-to-use-embedded-mongodb-with-springboot-v3-0-0